# How to write this in Cypher

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have around 644 nodes in my graph database(Neo4j) . I need to compute distances between  all these 644 nodes and display it visually in the GUI. I want to pre-compute and store the distances between every two pairs of nodes in  the database itself rather than retrieving the nodes on to the server and then finding the distances between them on the fly and then showing on the GUI.

I want to understand how to write such a query in CYPHER. Please let me know.

Comment: What does distance mean in your graph? Is it the number of relationships in the shortest path between to nodes? Or is it the function of some relationship property, a cheapest path or 'weighted shortest path' as they call it?

Comment: Distance is a similarity measure between two nodes.To make it clear,lets take an example .There are two kinds of nodes . One is user and other is books. Lets say John reads 10 books, Sam reads 5 books. Among both of them 4 books are common, then the distance between John and Sam is 4/(10+5-4) which is 4/11. In my applications, I have 644 users and 86000 books. I need to find such similarity among all the books. I want to store all distances (similarities) as the weights of edges in the graph

Answer (score 1):

I think this can work:

```
// half cross product
match (a),(b)
where id(a) < id(b)
match p=shortestPath((a)-[*]-(b))
with a,b,length(p) as l
create (a)-[:DISTANCE {distance:l}]->(b)
```

Set 4950 properties, created 4950 relationships, returned 0 rows in 4328 ms

But the browser viz will blow up with this, just that you know.

Regarding your distance measure (it won't be that fast but should work):

```
MATCH (a:User)-[:READ]->(book)<-[:READ]-(b:User)
WITH a,b,count(*) as common,
     length(a-[:READ]->()) as a_read,
     length(b-[:READ]->()) as b_read
CREATE UNIQUE (a)-[:DISTANCE {distance:common/(a_read+b_read-common)}]-(b)
```

Comment: Distance is a similarity measure between two nodes.To make it clear,lets take an example .There are two kinds of nodes . One is user and other is books. Lets say John reads 10 books, Sam reads 5 books. Among both of them 4 books are common, then the distance between John and Sam is 4/(10+5-4) which is 4/11. In my applications, I have 644 users and 86000 books. I need to find such similarity among all the books. I want to store all distances (similarities) as the weights of edges in the graph